# Mac OSX Terminal doesn't display PHP exceptions

Tags: php, macos, exception, terminal

Does anyone know what needs to be done for the terminal to display exceptions thrown by the PHP code? At the moment when I trigger for instance `php index.php` I don't get anything even though the code within the `index.php` file fires the exception.

I have all error logging set to true in my php.ini (running with Mamp).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have these lines **uncommented** in your default `php.ini`:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Comment: It's all uncommented, but still can't get them to display exceptions in terminal. They do show up when previewed in the browser, but not in terminal.

Comment: There are just the 2 lines I needed to uncomment on my OSX MAMP `php.ini`. Make sure you're editing correct ini file and it is not being overridden anywhere else. Check for `phpinfo();` output in browser and and search for `display_errors` on that page.

Comment: It's the correct file and these lines are exactly as above.

Comment: Did you check for `phpinfo();` output in browser and and search for `display_errors` on that page?